# Design pattern to save/load an object in various format

Tags: oop, design-patterns

I have an object: X, that can be saved or loaded in various formats: TXT, PDF, HTML, etc..

What is the best way to manage this situation? Add a pair of method to X for each format, create a new Class for each format, or exists (as I trust) a better solution?

Comment: In what programming language would you be implementing the solution? I can suggest various methods, but a few of them are facilitated by specific functionalities of a language/platform... delegates in .NET, anonymous classes in Java, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd choose the strategy pattern. For example:

```
interface XStartegy {
    X load();
    void save(X x);
}

class TxtStrategy implements XStartegy {
    //...implementation...
}

class PdfStrategy implements XStartegy {
    //...implementation...
}

class HtmlStrategy implements XStartegy {
    //...implementation...
}

class XContext {
    private XStartegy strategy;

    public XContext(XStartegy strategy) {
        this.strategy = strategy;
    }

    public X load() {
        return strategy.load();
    }

    public void save(X x) {
        strategy.save(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think if is X responsable of Strategy? I mean that X could have a nested interface `XStrategy`, an attribute `xstrategy`, and provide some commons implementations as `final static` like PDF_STRATEGY, TXT_STRATEGY and more.. ?

Comment: I don't really know why you would need constants when you have implementing classes like PdfStartegy, but you could solve this in any way you want, the patterns are just suggestions to a common way of solving known problems, and are not carved in stones. I believe the solution I gave here is the common way to implement it, but feel free to change it anyway you want. You can read more about it in here: http://www.oodesign.com/strategy-pattern.html

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @DarthVader , though in Java you'd better write

```
public class XDocument implements IDocument { ...
```

You could also use an abstract class, if much behavior is common to the documents, and in the common methods of base class call an abstract `save()`, which is only implemented in the subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with Factory pattern. It looks like you can use inheritance/polymorphism with generics. You can even do dependency injection if you go with the similar design as follows.

```
public interface IDocument
{
   void Save();
}

public class Document : IDocument
{


}

public class PdfDocument: IDocument
{
   public void Save(){//...}
}

public class TxtDocument: IDocument
{
   public void Save(){//...}
}

public class HtmlDocument : IDocument
{
  public void Save(){//...}
}
```

then in another class you can do this:

```
public void SaveDocument(T document) where T : IDocument
{
   document.save();
}
```

Comment: The problem is that my X object can born as TxtDocument, but the same object may be saved as PDF. With this solution if I load a TxtDocument, it can't saved as PDF, because both are IDocument, but a TxtDocument isn't a PDF.

Comment: isnt that the case, you should be able to save a txt document as a pdf document as well. no?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your objects, but it is possible, that visitor pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) can be used here. 
There are different visitors (PDFVisitor, HHTMLVisitor etc) that knows how to serialize parts of your objects that they visit.

Answer (score 0):

I would instead suggest the Strategy pattern.  You're always saving and restoring, the only difference is how you do it (your strategy).  So you have `save()` and `restore()` methods that defer to various `FormatStrategy` objects you can plug and play with at run time.